# Can't get Logical Error

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Firstly I 'll mention Absorption laws :

1. $((\sim p) \vee q) \wedge (\sim q)=(\sim p)$
   $((\sim p) \vee q) \wedge p=q$

Also, $p \Longrightarrow q = (\sim p) \vee q$

And, $p \Longleftrightarrow q = (p \Longrightarrow q) \wedge (q \Longrightarrow p)$

Let we have $p \Longrightarrow q = (\sim p) \vee q$
Now, given two absorption laws above, we have $p \Longrightarrow q = [((\sim p) \vee q) \wedge (\sim q)] \vee [(\sim p) \vee q) \wedge p]= [(\sim p) \vee q] \wedge [(\sim q) \vee p]$
So, This expression becomes $p \Longrightarrow q = p \Longleftrightarrow q.$

Where I'm mistaken ?

Comment: $[(∼p)∨q]∧[(∼p)∨q]$ is $(p \to q) \land (p \to q)$  i.e. $p \to q$ and **not** $p \leftrightarrow q$.

Comment: Please see my edit, I used distributive law

Comment: Are you sure your absorption laws are correct? For example, we have $((\sim p) \vee q)\wedge (\sim q) = ((\sim p) \wedge (\sim q)) \vee (q\wedge(\sim q)) = (\sim p) \wedge (\sim q) \neq (\sim p).$

Comment: Oh, I see .. But if you apply your intuition I see these laws are correct, because if we have two options with another is denied, then second one is preferred. Isn't?

Comment: (∼p)∨q)∧(∼q)=(∼p) is not a law.  Let p=0, and q=1.  Then the left hand side evaluates to 0, but the right evaluates to 1.  ((∼p)∨q)∧p=q is also not a law.  Let q=1, and p=0.

Answer (score 2):

*Correction*

Applying [Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) to : $(\lnot p∨q)∧\lnot q$ we get :

> $(\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (q \land \lnot q) \equiv (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor F \equiv (\lnot p \land \lnot q).$

In the same way :

> $(\lnot p ∨ q)∧p \equiv (p \land q)$.

---

[Absorption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_%28logic%29) is :

> $(\lnot p \lor q) \equiv (\lnot p \lor (p \land q))$.